# How to call javascript class function from closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, closures

I'm working on a jQuery plugin that does not have a selector. When initializing it, I instanciate an object that has functions. In these functions, I need to use closures. In these closures, I would like to call my initial object functions.

To make it more clear, here is a simplified version of the code.

**HTML**

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/my/script/myeditor.js"></script>

<div class="editable">Div1</div>
<div class="editable">Div2</div>

<script>
    $.myeditor({
        option1: 'a',
        option2: 'b'
    });
</script>
```

**myeditor.js**

```
function ($) {

var MyEditor = function (options)
{
    this.$options = $.extend(true, {}, $.myeditor.defaults, options);
    this.init();
};

$.myeditor = function (options = {})
{
    return new MyEditor(options);
};

$.flyeditor.defaults = {
    option1: '1',
    option2: '2'
};

MyEditor.prototype.notify = function(message = '')
{
    console.log(message);
};

MyEditor.prototype.init = function()
{
    // Do stuff
    $('.editables').each(function() {
        $this = $(this);

        // Here comes the error
        notify($this.html());
    });
};

}(jQuery);
```

The problem is that `notify(this.html());` raises an error `ReferenceError: notify is not defined`

How can I reach this notify method?

Comment: `MyEditor.prototype.notify = function(message = ''){` is not valid JavaScript, are you using a preprocessor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assign `this` to a separate local variable in a closure. You need to do that because `this` will no longer point to your `MyEditor` object inside the `each`, it will point to each of the `.editables`

Also, you probably meant to call `this.notify()`, since the function is attached to the prototype of `MyEditor`

```
MyEditor.prototype.init = function()
{
    // Do stuff
    var that = this; // <-- now we can reach this inside function.
    $('.editables').each(function() {
        $this = $(this);

        // Here comes the error
        // You can't use notify, that function is not defined
        // You can't use this.notify because this points to something else (the node)
        // inside the function in each
        that.notify($this.html());
    });
};
```

Comment: this is actually EXACTLY what OP is asking about. He can't reach notify as it is on the prototype, thus needing `this`, but since he is in a closure, `this` needs to be assigned to something outside the closure to access it within.

Comment: @Juhana `this` is different context inside `each`

Comment: I've backtracked twice on this (no pun intended, really), upvote back, adding some more explanation to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyEditor.prototype.init = function()
{
// Do stuff
var self = this;
$('.editables').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);

    // Here comes the error
    self.notify($this.html());
});
};
```

Comment: This is the same thing that [Jimmy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27800676/227299) already mentioned